# BroadcastReceiver DATE_CHANGED не срабатывает в закрытом приложении

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

Настроил BroadcastRecever, который стирает данные приложения при изменении системной даты (Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED;). 
Когда приложение запущено, он работает, однако хотелось бы, чтобы это receiver срабатывал и когда приложение отключено

AndroidManifest, где прописан ресивер

```
<receiver android:name=".myAirplaneReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Сам ресивер

```
public class myAirplaneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences sPref = context.getSharedPreferences ( "drawableId", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit ();
    ed.remove ( "drawableId" );
    ed.remove ( "textId" );
    ed.apply ();
}
```

Может ресивер еще где-то надо прописать? и если надо, подскажите примерно как.
С синтаксисом все еще большие проблемы(

Comment: Должно работать. Расскажите как вы отключаете приложение. Если ему `forceStop` делать то ничего работать точно не будет пока приложение не будет перезапущено.

Comment: Отключаю стандартным способом Android. Свайпом вверх в окне запущенных приложений